# How can I use pytorch to implement layer pruning of my own defined resnet series models?

Tags: pytorch, pruning

Hello everyone！This is my initial question. Thank you very much for your help.

I now want to directly delete a certain convolutional layer in my model, such as a convolutional layer in resnet18 with an input of 64 channels and an output of 128 channels. My current problem is that if I directly remove this convolutional layer and directly connect the i-1 layer (the output is 64 channels) and the i+1 layer (the input is 128 channels), the outputs will not match the inputs. What should I do?

Another solution is that if I replace the original convolution kernel with 1*1 convolution kernels in the i-th layer, and only realize the function of matching the output of the i-1 layer and the input of the i+1 layer, then these convolution kernels What parameters should I set to? My scenario is to replace this layer and use it directly without any fine-tuning process or changing the parameters of other layers.